# Maven error in Jenkins JMeter project, "Error creating properties files for forking"

Tags: maven, jenkins, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have Maven JMeter project which runs perfectly from my home folder using "mvn verify", but when I try to run it from Jenkins I get error message to console:

> ```
> [workspace] $ mvn verify
> FATAL: command execution failed
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/PerformanceTests/workspace"): error=2, No such
> ```
>
> file or directory"

If I try to run "mvn verify" manually from folder where Jenkins tries to run it (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/PerformanceTests/workspace), I get error message:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test
>   (default-test) on project jmeter: Error creating properties files for
>   forking; nested exception is java.io.IOException: No such file or
>   directory -> [Help 1]

My pom is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>perftest</groupId>
  <artifactId>jmeter</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>jmeter</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

All other jobs in the same Jenkins base folder "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs" are working fine. I also use git plugin with Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's still struggling with this - I was able to solve it by changing owner of the directory to the current username, instead of root.

Answer (score 0):

John,
  I just ran into this exact problem. I'm not 100% sure on the reason, but I was *unable* to get this to work when I created a standard Jenkins job and added a Maven build step. *However*, when I created a Maven project (currently called "Build a maven2/3 project" in the Jenkins New Job setup menu, Jenkins version 1.541), it worked just fine. Give that a try if you're still having a problem (though I know your question is a little old now).

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, I have to try that when I have time. I made some workaround, iirc launched JMeter using command line option.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is too late to answer but still if it can be useful to someone. Just to answer your first error code block, Jenkins doesn't accept "mvn" as part of the command when trying to execute a Maven Job. Just pass your goals like, 
    clean verify

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the disk size! I removed a big file (`nohup.out`), it worked.